# Removing DataFrame rows by comparing dates

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataset and only wants to have the rows inside a time range. 
I put all the good rows in a Series object. But when I re-assign that object to the DataFrame object, I get NaT values:

code:

```
def get_tweets_from_range_in_csv():
    csvfile1 = "results_dataGOOGL050"
    df1 = temp(csvfile1)


def temp(csvfile):
    tweetdats = []
    d = pd.read_csv(csvfile + ".csv", encoding='latin-1')
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-01-2018", "%d-%m-%Y")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-06-2018", "%d-%m-%Y")
    for index, current_tweet in d['Date'].iteritems():
        date_tw = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_tweet[:10], "%Y-%m-%d")
        if start <= date_tw <= end:
            tweetdats.append(date_tw)
        else:
            d.drop(index, inplace=True)
    d = d.drop("Likes", 1)
    d = d.drop("RTs", 1)
    d = d.drop("Sentiment", 1)
    d = d.drop("User", 1)
    d = d.drop("Followers", 1)
    df1['Date'] = pd.Series(tweetdats)
    return d
```

Output of tweetdats:

```
tweetdats
Out[340]: 
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 30, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 20, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to iterate through your dataframe with a `for` loop to select the rows inside the time range of interest.

Let us assume that your initial dataframe  `df` has a 'Date' column containing the dates in datetime format; you can then simply create a new dataframe `new_df`:

```
new_df=df[(pd.to_datetime(df.time) > start) & (pd.to_datetime(self.df.time) < end)]
```

This way you do not have to copy and paste the "good" rows in a Series and then reassign them to a dataframe.

Your `temp` function would look like:

```
def temp(csvfile):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile + ".csv", encoding='latin-1')
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-01-2018", "%d-%m-%Y")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-06-2018", "%d-%m-%Y")
    new_df=df[(pd.to_datetime(df.time) > start) & (pd.to_datetime(self.df.time) < end)]
```

Hope this helps!